# Algorithms- uniform random element linked lists

Tags: c++

How would get a uniform random element from a linked list? By counting the length of list
and as you are counting, generate a random element. If the random element % length of list 
equal 0, then choose that element.

Comment: You should read about std::list. It will help you in generic programming. There is a function which return size.

Answer (score 1):

You need the length of the list first before you can start picking an element, thus it needs on average 1,5 iterations through the list.

The first will be for getting the length of the list.
Then get a random number of [0...1] multiplied by the length of the list, rounded down.
That is the index you have to get (you have to go for another iteration).

in pseudo code:

```
int n = list.size()  // Returns length of list
int index = (int) (random_value() * n); // random_value returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0
int* node = list.start() // goto start of list
for (int iter = 0; 0 < n; n++)
    node = node->next() // Goto next node
return node
```

Comment: ok. but while I traverse through the list I need generate a random element at each node. Then using computing (random element % length) == 0.

Comment: No you don't, I write it in my answer.